# flot date bar chart alignment askew

Tags: javascript, datetime, flot

I am trying to make a chart that shows the number of search results my app pulls in for each day using flot. My code (BTW it uses underscore.js):

```
flotDataSet = _.countBy(resultSet, function(file) {
    var exactDate = new Date(parseInt(file.get('start_utc'), 10));

    //constructing a new date with 0 time so that all days get grouped together.
    return new Date(exactDate.getUTCFullYear(), exactDate.getUTCMonth(), exactDate.getUTCDate()).getTime();
});

flotDataSet = _.map(flotDataSet, function(value, key) {
    return [key, value];
});

$.plot(
    $graphDiv,
    [{
        data: flotDataSet,
        color: '#012D4C',
        bars: { show: true, fillColor: '#024985', align: 'center', fill: 0.7, barWidth: DateUtil.msInDay/2 }
    }],
    {
        grid: { color: '#012D4C' },
        xaxis: {
            mode: 'time',
            tickSize: [1, 'day'],
            autoscaleMargin: 0.001
        }
    }
);
```

Outputs something like this:

[image]

I really need the bars to center around the day. Any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bUa3R/

Comment: That's weird. It's working in my jsFiddle, but not in my web app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the problem. My Date generation code was off because JavaScript's long-form `Date(year, month, date [, time...])` constructor uses the local time or something weird like that. Anyway, I replaced the call to `new Date(...).getTime()` to be `Date.UTC(...)` and everything magically worked.

Seems like JavaScript's Date handling tends to be the root of most of my JS problems!